# Why can't a static data member has the same name with non-static data member?

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int x = 1;
class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
        x = 3;
    }
    static int x;
    void bar() const
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    int x;
};
int foo::x = 2;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

here's the compiler output:

```
test.cc:19:9: error: ‘int foo::x’ conflicts with a previous declaration
     int x;
         ^
test.cc:14:16: note: previous declaration ‘int foo::x’
     static int x;
```

Comment: Its the same principle that you can't have two variables with the same name in a function(doesnt matter if one of them is static) within the same scope.

Comment: Because otherwise you wouldn't know which was which. The program would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

They can't have the same name because which one would you mean when you refer to `x` in a non-static method?

The language designers could have decided to allow it, e.g. to prefer the non-static one or the reverse.  But personally I'm glad they didn't.

Comment: well, I know we can both omitted the this pointer and the foo:: for convenience. But it is still strange because they are from two different context.

Comment: @hustxujinkang They are from one *scope*: the class scope.